# Wrong positions of group bars in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to draw group bar plot using `MatPlotLib` but positions of my bars is wrong.

So, I have a data:

```
groups = [
    np.array([ group1.count(0), group1.count(1) ]),
    np.array([ group2.count(0), group2.count(1) ]),
]
```

The `group` is `[[1, 3], [0, 5]]`, and that means that each group has two colors. In first group just 1 people choose the first color, and other 3 people choose the second color. I am trying to draw it but positions of bars are wrong: `3` from the first group moved to the second group and so on.

[image]

Where is my mistake and why that happens?

The code to draw the data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def draw(groups):
    group_labels = ['G1', 'G2']
    num_items = len(group_labels)
    ind = np.arange(num_items)
    margin = 0.05
    width = (1.-2.*margin)/num_items
    colors = ['#f5abb5', '#2fc2ef']

    s = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    for num, vals in enumerate(groups):
        xdata = ind+margin+(num*width)
        plt.bar(xdata, vals, width, color=colors[num])
    s.set_xticks(ind+0.5)
    s.set_xticklabels(group_labels)


draw(groups)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may transpose the input array

```
groups = numpy.array([[1, 3], [0, 5]]).T
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!